# Where was Homura taken?

Tags: madoka-magica

In the Rebellion movie, just as Homura was about to become a witch and be claimed by the Law of Cycles, the Incubators trapped her Soul Gem in an Isolation Field.

When the magical girls break the field there seemed to be thousands of Incubators gathered in one place and it was quite barren. Where did the Incubators take Homura, and if it was their homeworld, how did Mami, Kyouko, Hitomi, and Kyosuke get there?

Comment: Your guess is as good as anybody's. It's probably not the Incubator homeworld, though. Keep in mind that there must be lots of Kyuubeys on Earth - whenever one of them dies (like in episode 8), another one appears from god-knows-where to take its place

Comment: @senshin i thought their homeworld because on earth they would be scattered yet they were all gathered in one place, but they are supposed to be technologically advance so that doesn't explain the barren landscape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it is on Earth, but on a deserted location (or a post-apocalyptic Earth). During the movie it is mentioned that Kyouko and Mami entered the Isolation Field by coincidence (so did Madoka's parents). They could only have entered this Field if it were located somewhere on Earth.